# How to make scrapy requests synchronous

Tags: python-3.x, loops, request, scrapy, synchronous

I recently started to use Scrapy and Python, so please bear with me.
I based my code from this 
[tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-scrape-websites-based-on-viewstates-using-scrapy-39feb9445755).
I need to get some information from all cities of my country (Brazil) in different years from this [website](https://aplicacoes.mds.gov.br/suaswebcons/restrito/execute.jsf?b=*dpotvmubsQbsdfmbtQbhbtNC&event=*fyjcjs). 
The options of the dropdown are generated dynamically with an AJAX request. Thus, first I get all years and states, then I make an request to get the cities from each state.

I learnt that if I use a return inside my loop, as in the code, it will finish my function, the problem is that, if I use an YIELD the request follow no order (probably because the requests are asynchronous? Let me know the reason as well), i.e it makes a request to a city with the wrong state. Therefore, I receive the wrong response.
By the way, although using the return it finishes the function, it make the correct request.

```
def parse(self, response):
        years = response.xpath(...).getall()
        states = response.xpath(...).getall()`

        # Start from the second element since the first one is '-- Select --'
        for year in years[1:]:
            for state in states[1:]:
                print (year)
                print (state)        
                # I need this request to get all cities from the current state, since it's generated with an AJAX REQUEST
                request = { ...,
                  callback = self.parse_city
                return request

    def parse_city(self, response):
        keys = response.xpath(...).getall()
        values = response.xpath(...).getall()

        # Build dictionary with the key (city IBGE code) and value (city name)
        cities = dict(zip(keys[1:], values[1:]))

        for code, city in cities.items():
            request = ...,
              callback = self.parse_result
            return request

    def parse_result(self, response):
        yield {
           #The information that I want
        }
```

My requests are created inside the loop, what I'd expect to happen is: 
  First: print the year and the state and then make request.
  Second: the callback would grab all cities and make a request for that 
    city, in that state in that year. 
  Third: the parse_result would fetch the information that I need.
Instead what happens is that it print all year and state, which means it's not executing synchronously

How do I make this synchronous? How can I make sure that my requests will follow the correct order of my array?

Thanks a lot in advance

Tying to be more clear:

```
for each year   
    select year   
    for each state
        select state
        wait for cities options to load
        for each city
            get the information
```

Comment: The solution was to set the `CONCURRENT_REQUEST=1` as suggested by @Thiago Curvelo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the problem here is because the session information is stored in a stateful server. Right?

A way to handle this would be having one session for each state, managing it through cookiejars. E.g:

```
for year in years[1:]:
    for state in states[1:]:
        yield Request(
            # ...,
            callback=self.parse_city, 
            meta={'cookiejar': state} 
        )
```

More info about [`cookiejars`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#multiple-cookie-sessions-per-spider).

And yes, the requests in scrapy are scheduled to run asynchronously. That why we should provide callback functions to it.

Comment: Not quite, the problem is that it isn't running synchronously. Sorry, I know I'm not being clear enough. But I think is easy to understand with the last code, the problem is that the loop isn't waiting for the requests responses. Therefore everything is scattered. Trying to print the year and state inside the loop instead of printing them before each request it will print all values at once. Is that a better explanation? Hope it helps. Thanks

Comment: Well, definitely this isn't the better solution, but you could set `CONCURRENT_REQUEST=1`. Give it a try and check if it works as you wish.

Comment: Nice, it worked with that, now it's getting one by one correctly. Would you say that the problem was trying to make several requests at the same time? The default seems to be 16, so I don't why that would be the problem. but for me the CONCURRENT_REQUEST=1  worked fine :)

Comment: No, concurrency is usually what we want in our spiders. To be honest, I still don't understand exactly what problems you were facing with the async requests. But, answering your original question, setting it to 1 is a way to ensure that requests are made synchronously.

Comment: I see, maybe my problem isn't with the async at all and I'm dwelling on the wrong thing, as I said I'm new at Scrapy and Python. Here is the code [https://gitlab.com/saulofsouza/suas_web_crawler] maybe you'll understand if you run it. Thank you anyway, it helped a lot my friend.